# How would you put back a list that you've split and transformed back to the original file?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to isolate date from date/time which is a column in the original csv file. I've isolated the column and change it to just date but I am having a tough time putting it back to the original file:

```
def isolateDate(csv_file):
    file_in = open(csv_file, "rU")
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    next(file_in,None)
    for line in reader:
        date = line[3]
        date = date.split()
        new_date = date[0]
    return new_date
```

How would I go about putting back `new_date` variable as the `line[3]` in the original file

Comment: You can't just rewrite part of the file, you need to rewrite the whole thing with your new data. Does the file only contain dates-times?

Comment: it's a big file with names, and 27 other columns, I was hoping  to just change one of it's column. How would you bring about writing the whole file with the new changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to read in all the rows from the file, modify the 4th column (index 3) and then rewrite back to file:

```
with open(csv_file, "r") as file_in:
    reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    header = next(reader)
    rows = [row[0:3] + [row[3].split()[0]] + row[4:]  for row in reader]
    #                  ^^^modified date^^^

with open(csv_file, "w") as file_in:
    writer = csv.writer(file_in)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```